# Automatically add new column to incremental (or other type)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I need some wisdom for a new  DBT use case that I am trying to solve. I am pretty new to DBT and not sure what is the most efficient DBT way. We are using snowflake as our DWH.

#### Problem

We have a lot of incremental models that are managed with DBT. Lately, we had the need to add a new column to all models. What would be the most efficient DBT way to do it? Should we override the incremental macro script? ([I found this for snowflake](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-snowflake/blob/main/dbt/include/snowflake/macros/materializations/incremental.sql).) I assume that the last resort will be to add the new column manually to each model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either `--full-refresh` all the incremental models or perform this schema migration outside of dbt.

I would recommend using `--full-refresh` if you are able to. since `--full-refresh` rebuilds the table, it takes care of the schema changes and the historical values of the new column.

On the current version of dbt `v0.21.0`, a new incremental setting was introduced, [`on_schema_change`](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/building-models/configuring-incremental-models). You can set it to `append_new_columns`

Quoting some relevant sections from the documentation:

> New on_schema_change config in dbt version v0.21.0
> Incremental models can now be configured to include an optional on_schema_change parameter to enable additional control when incremental model columns change. These options enable dbt to continue running incremental models in the presence of schema changes, resulting in fewer --full-refresh scenarios and saving query costs.

> append_new_columns: Append new columns to the existing table. Note that this setting does not remove columns from the existing table that are not present in the new data.

> Note: None of the on_schema_change behaviors backfill values in old records for newly added columns. If you need to populate those values, we recommend running manual updates, or triggering a --full-refresh.

If `--full-refresh` is not an option or you're on an older dbt version, then your schema migration would have to be done manually.

The steps are:

1. add the new column via an alter table `alter table my_incremental_table add column new_column_name data_type`
2. run an update query to hydrate the new column
3. edit the dbt model for `my_incremental_table` to add `new_column_name` to the end of the select query's list of columns

This will work because dbt is stateless, but as this is a manual operation, I don't recommend this if you can avoid it.

note also, that if you use the `on_schema_change` method, you'd still need to do a backfill of the new column manually.

Comment: Thanks @HaleemurAli. Not sure I understand how --full-refresh will help this situation. Also, alter table add column, I am not sure if thats an option since we need to add a Jinja logic column for example ```{% if var('id') %} '{{ var("id") }}' {% else %} null {% endif %} as id``` and since we've got a few dozens I do not wish to edit each .sql file.
I found this ```The --full-refresh flag will force dbt to drop cascade the existing table before rebuilding it.``` so I am not sure I want to drop the existing table

Comment: @ShayHa, I'm not sure what the `jinja-logic` column is doing. are you passing in a variable through the CLI called `id` and determines what is used to build the `id` column. If yes, then I think you may have a different data modelling issue as well, though I can't be sure with the information that I have. if you're on the most recent version of dbt, there's a new parameter for incremental models to control what happens when a column gets added `on_schema_change`, that automates the schema change on the incremental model by introspecting the defining query & the database schema. answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to understand how to override the ``` incremental.sql``` macro and I will add my logic there so every run will insert another column to all incremental models.